# line graph with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following data state wise patents information for the year 2000 up to 2004

```
States;2000;2001;2002;2003;2004
state1;12302;11610;12297;13291;13491
state2;13010;14304;13599;13761;14398
state3;1242;1228;1099;1109;1016
state4;398;399;379;408;361
state5;164;198;143;158;185
state6;1185;1427;1166;955;1105
```

I am loading this data in to a DataFrame using pandas

```
patents = pd.read_csv('Patent.csv', encoding='ANSI', 
                     sep=';', header=0, skiprows=0, 
                     names=['States','Year'],
                     index_col=['States'])
```

but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly because my data I have two headers. (States and Years)
When I use to create a graph of this data using

```
patents.plot(kind='line')
```

It does not display the line graph of no. of patents between states and years:

[image]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
patents.set_index('States').T.plot(kind='line')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. this is exactly what i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have 5 columns YEARS, but you give name to only one.
You either need to have 5 YEARS columns:

```
patents = pd.read_csv('Patent.csv', encoding='ANSI', 
    sep=';', header=0, skiprows=0, 
    names=['States','2000','2001','2002','2003','2004'],
    index_col=['States'])
```

or change you data to have strings:

```
States;Years
state1;"12302,11610,12297,13291,13491"
state2;"13010,14304,13599,13761,14398"
```

Answer (score 0):

Also Try:

```
patents =pd.read_csv('patents.csv',sep=';',encoding='ANSI',index_col='States')
patents .transpose().plot(kind='line')
patents .transpose().plot(kind='bar')
```